# Visual Studio Code rebuilds for no good reason

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Background:**

- When the project is already running (npm run start), and I make changes, and save. Then VS Code rebuilds and runs the project. Great!
- But it is very frustrating when VS Code is running, and you look through the code (without changing or saving anything), then often VS Code rebuilds for no reason.
- When this happens, one loses the DevTools browser inspector, and has to start all over again.

**Questions:**

1. So, is there a way to prevent VS Code from automatically rebuilding without having changed or saved anything?
2. And is it possible to keep the auto-rebuild-on-save functionality at the same time?

Comment: Rebuilds what? Are there missing tags/context?

Comment: @sindri_baldur It rebuilds the project and runs it. The same effect as when you save changes.

Comment: Define "project"

Comment: Hey @sindri_baldur, I changed the wording. Maybe it is clearer now.